# Pygame NameError: free variable 'lost' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, pygame

I have recently been working on a Space Invaders game in Pygame via Tech with Tim YouTube tutorial and have encounter a name error on line 111:

> NameError: free variable 'lost' referenced before assignment in
> enclosing scope.

Link to the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-__8Xw9KTM&feature=youtu.be&t=1112

Code:

```
import pygame
import os
import time
import random
import math
import sys

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

#Game Variables 
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()



#Ships
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_ship_red_small.png'))
GREEN_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_ship_green_small.png'))
BLUE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_ship_blue_small.png'))
YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_ship_yellow.png'))

#Lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_laser_red.png'))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_laser_blue.png'))
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_laser_yellow.png'))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','pixel_laser_green.png'))

#Background
BG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','background-black.png')).convert_alpha())


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0
    
    def draw(self, window):
        screen.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))

    def get_width(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_width()

    def get_height(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_height()

class Player(Ship):
    def __init__(self,x,y, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img = YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP
        self.laser_img = YELLOW_LASER
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
        self.max_health = health
        
class Enemy(Ship):
    COLOUR_MAP = {
                 "red": (RED_SPACE_SHIP, RED_LASER),
                 "green": (GREEN_SPACE_SHIP, GREEN_LASER),
                 "blue": (BLUE_SPACE_SHIP, BLUE_LASER),
                 }
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, colour, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.COLOUR_MAP[colour]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel
        

        
def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    level = 0
    lives = 5
    main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)
    lost_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 60)

    enemies = []
    wave_length = 5
    enemy_vel = 1

    player_vel = 5

    player = Player(300, 650)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def redraw_window():
        screen.blit(BG, (0,0))

        lives_label = main_font.render(f'Lives: {lives}', 1, (255,255,255))
        level_label= main_font.render(f'Level: {level}', 1, (255,255,255))

        screen.blit(lives_label, (10,10))
        screen.blit(level_label, (WIDTH - level_label.get_width() - 10, 10))


        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw(screen)

        player.draw(screen)

        if lost:
            lost_label = lost_font.render("You Lost!!", 1, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(lost_label, (WIDTH/2 - lost_label.get_width()/2, 350))
            

        
        pygame.display.update()



    while True:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw_window()

        if lives <= 0 or player.health <= 0:
            lost = True
            lost_count += 1

        if len(enemies) == 0:
            level += 1
            wave_length += 5
            for i in range(wave_length):
                enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"]))
                enemies.append(enemy)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x - player_vel > 0:
            player.x -= player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x + player_vel + player.get_width() < WIDTH:
            player.x += player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.y - player_vel > 0:
            player.y -= player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.y + player_vel + player.get_height() < HEIGHT:
            player.y += player_vel

        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.move(enemy_vel)
            if enemy.y + enemy.get_height() > HEIGHT:
                lives -= 1
                enemies.remove(enemy)
        
     

main()
```

Comment: You don't define the variable `lost` in the `main` function as Tim does: https://youtu.be/Q-__8Xw9KTM?t=4055

Answer (score 0):

For `lost` and `lost_count`, you need to mark them as global so the method does not treat them as local variables:

In your code, replace this:

```
def main():
```

With this:

```
lost = False
lost_count = 0
        
def main():

    # use global variables
    global lost
    global lost_count
```

Comment: global must be on its own line. Set the variables before `main()` and use `global` in `main()`. Just copy\paste the new code and it should work.

Comment: Or just define the variables directly in the main function. That way you don't need to use global variables which clutters your namespace and makes it harder to reason about where it's being modified